# Xcode issue navigator : What two arrows blue icon mean?

Tags: xcode

On Xcode Version 7.3.1 (7D1014), on in the Issue navigator, I have an icon at the right of the project line I can't understand.

Do you know what does it mean ?

[image]

Comment: Static analyzer issue, I guess project has memory management issues and other.

Comment: You're right. Post your comment as an answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this is actually a `Static Analyzer` issue.
It occurs when project has memory management issues and other.

More info on this could be found here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/chapters/Analyze.html